# Prevent access to a folder in WINE (running on Lubuntu)

Tags: command-line, permissions, wine

I have a windows executable that takes in a project file name and runs it this way, under WINE (on Lubuntu). I call the below line through a batch file that resides in the same application directory

```
myruntime.exe myapplicationname.prj
```

The project file (myapplicationname.prj) along with some other source files (python, js etc) are all in a folder in the wine c drive:\myapplication

Now as my folder contains some Proprietary code, I want to prevent the code from being copied or accessed. How can this be achieved?

In simple terms I want WINE to be able to execute the windows executable and have access to the necessary folders but I do not want anything or anyone else to access the contents of the folder.

I need to distribute little Linux(Ubuntu/Lubuntu) boxes with my application on it and I need my source to be protected. For now there is no way to compile the source files and I have spent a lot of effort writing the program. Kindly suggest.

I am a little new to Linux so having a little detailed steps will help greatly. Thanks once again. If I am not clear in my question, please let me know so that I can clarify or rephrase it.

Thanks in advance, M&M

Answer (score 1):

[AppArmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) should be able to do things like this. It's a access control layer that can add additional conditioons on user and processes. I've never used it before though so you might have some trial and error ahead of you.

There's [a fairly thorough guide](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/QuickProfileLanguage) on all of this on the AppArmor wiki. You'll need to layer more and more on but here's a starting point.

```
/usr/bin/wine {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/user-tmp>

  audit deny /path/to/directory/**    rwx,
}
```

There's also [a separate wiki page on Wine applications in AppArmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmorWine). Probably worth a read.